# XML - java tool for automatic tag inserting

Tags: java, xml, tags, editing

Is there a java tool, that allows automatic editing of XML files according to a configuration?

Let say, i want to add the tag `<foo>hello</foo>` after every tag `<boo>` in a file.

I would appreciate a tool, where i can config a text and a location (after tag, into tag) and the tool automatically edit target XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) stylesheets - you can define rules to convert XML to another, possibly non-XML, format. [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) is a command-line tool to apply an XSLT transform to an XML file. There are also GUI-based tools but I can't recommend any.

Comment: Although i want something simpler to configuration, this is certainly possible solution. Because i could not find an other solution, i made the XSLT transform, as you suggested.